# Dynamically blocking IPs in high-traffic site: best strategy?

Tags: php, performance, apache

I've got some bad bots targeting my website and I need to dynamically handle the IP addresses from which those bots come. It's a pretty high-traffic site, we get a couple of millions of pageviews per day and that's why we're using 4 servers (loadbalanced). We don't use any caching (besides assets) because most of our responses are unique.

Code-technically it's a pretty small PHP website, which does no database queries and one XML request per pageview. The XML request get's a pretty *fast* response.

I've developed a script to (very frequently) analyse which IP addresses are doing abusive requests and I want to handle requests from those IPs differently for a certain amount of time. The IPs that are abusive change a lot so I need to block different IPs every couple of minutes

So: I see IP xx.xx.xx.xx being abusive, I record this somewhere and then I want to give that IP a special treatment for the next x minutes it does requests. I need to do this in a fast way, because I don't want to slow down the server and have the legitimate users suffer for this.

**Solution 1: file**

Writing the abusive IPs down in a file and then reading that file for every request seems
too slow. Would you agree?

**Solution 2:PHP include**

I could let my analysis script write a PHP include file which the PHP engine then would include for every request. But: I can imagine that, while writing the PHP file, a lot of users that do a request right then get an error because the file is being used.

I could solve that potential problem by writing the file and then doing a symlink change (which might be faster).

**Solution 3: htaccess**

Another way to separate the abusers out would be to write an htacces that blocks or redirects them. This might be the most efficient way but I need to write an htaccess file every x minutes then.

I'd love to hear some thoughts/reactions on my proposed solutions, especially concerning speed.

Comment: Agreed with your 3 solutions. I guess there is a fourth one : I'm handling this with iptables and fail2ban rather than with the server php response, but did not benchmark both solutions speed. Another working solution as you mentionned is to use a "Include /etc/apache2/extra/redirecting_rules" in your server vhost ;  I did not benchmark that one either but it might be slower because of the systematic required file accesses.

Comment: .htaccess does not scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about dynamically configuring `iptables` to block the bad IPs?  I don't see any reason to do the "firewalling" in PHP...

Comment: I'd like to not *block* the IPs but send them to another page with a CAPTCHA or some other barrier to entry. If a legitimate user is handled this way he can then still use the service. A bad bot wouldn't bother, at least I hope.

Comment: `iptables` can do more than block - you can change the destination IP address as well i.e. redirect to a different server if you want.  Also I'd think any decent load-balancer could do this for you as well.  All of your 3 solutions seem to me to boil down to a file read on every request, which can probably be OK if you are still only handling 20-30 transactions per second, but it's probably a good idea to implement something more scalable ahead of time.

Comment: Doing this on the level of iptables is out of my comfort zone and out of my "jurisidiction" as developer. Also I'd like to have this under my control as much as possible. See my answer for how I've implemented this.

Comment: I've given you the accepted answer as I think iptables probably is the most performant solution, even though the solution I've picked is performant enough for my needs, for now.

Answer (score 1):

**For the record** I've finally decided to go for (my own proposed) solution number 2, generating a PHP file that is included on every page request.

The complete solution is as follows:
A Python script analyses the accesslog file every x minutes and doles out "punishments" to certain IP addresses. All currently running punishments are written into a fairly small (<1Kb)   PHP file. This PHP file is included for every page request. Directly after generation of the PHP file an rsync job is started to push the new PHP file out to the other 3 servers behind the loadbalancer.

In the Python script that generates the PHP file I first concatenate the complete contents of the file. I then open, write and close the file sequentially to lock the file for the shortest possible period.

Comment: I prefer Python for doing serverside stuff not involving HTML, like analyzing big chunks of data.

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously consider putting up another server that holds the (constantly changing) block list in-memory and serves the front-end servers.
I implemented such a solution using Node.JS and found the implementation easy and performance very good.
memcached could also be used, but I never tried it.